# MVC 3 Razor - Unobtrusive Validation Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

Can anyone see why my validation is not working?  Currently it just posts and fails on the insert because the data insert doesn't allow nulls instead of catching it client-side and displaying the required field messages.

**View**
http://pastebin.com/4grwD02i

**Controller**
http://pastebin.com/jdbYk8tR

**Layout**
http://pastebin.com/AbQ9xYLG

**AppSettings**

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

### ~~UPDATE~~

**Model**
http://pastebin.com/FJkPgKsX

I'm just using a Linq to SQL DBML file for my DAL so, no I haven't done any decorating of properties.  Can I do this and still use DBML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default model binder relies on data annotations in order to perform validation. So if your model properties don't have any attributes to indicate how validation is performed it will always be considered as valid (except for example in cases where you are trying to bind invalid formats to a `DateTime` or `int` fields when the default model binder will automatically mark the model state as invalid).

Comment: I am not able to do the data annotations in my partial class without getting an error: *The type 'Yes.Models.MobileCarrier' already contains a definition for 'Name'*

Comment: @EdenMachine, you could use `[MetaDataType]` attribute to externalize the validation into a separate class. See this article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any of your action methods checking to see if the model state is valid. Your action methods will execute regardless of if the validation on the page is valid. To check to see if all of your validation has been passed, check the `ModelState.IsValid` property.

Is `ModelState.IsValid` is false, then do not perform any actions against your data store. Most people simply render the same view as before, and the helpers will do their job of putting in the user's data and displaying the validation.

EDIT:
After looking at your post, you are probably expecting the post to never happen since you are trying to use client-side validation. I don't have as much experience with this part of the validation, but even if you want to use it, you shouldn't fully rely on it and always rely on the server to do the validation for you (the client-side validation should mainly be there for a better user experience).

I'm not sure what your model looks like, but I'm assuming you've decorated the various properties and/or fields with attributes from the `System.ComponentModel` namespace, correct?

Comment: I updated my post to answer your questions.  (And feel free to point out any other dumb things I'm doing - I'm completely new to MVC.  This is my first try at it.)

Comment: I added the **ModelState.IsValid** around my controller insert code and it returns as **true**

Comment: It looks like @Darin has you going down the right path, once you look into `MetaDataTypeAttribute`, it should become more clear on what to do. But I would warn you against binding request data to your models that persist to the database. If someone knows your model well enough, they can format a request such that it binds the properties you never intended them to be able to bind to (such as the primary key). Most people use View Models instead, it's an extra layer you have to convert the data into, but allows you to define a model that fits the exact needs of your various views.